# Unable to retrieve entity values from LUIS in Microsoft Bot framework (node.js)

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

Deployed a LUIS template on Azure's new Bot Service. Tested the code locally and it works perfectly. However, on loading the same code into the bot service, I am unable to retrieve entities produced by LUIS.

Here is the section of code:

```
bot.dialog('/', intents);

intents.matches('getWeather',[
function(session, args, next)
{
    //session.send("Inside weather intent")
    var intent = args.intent;
    var location = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'place');
```

I also tried the following:

```
var location = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'place');
```

And finally:

```
var location = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intent.entities, 'place');
```

Can't seem to retrieve the entities. I tried the following code locally with i/o on the console and it works fine:

```
bot.dialog('/', dialog);
dialog.matches('getWeather',[
function(session, args, next)
{
    console.log("Inside weather intent")
    var location = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'place');
```

The LUIS model has been trained and I cross-checked the API variables. The intent is correctly recognized and triggered as well. The output is either "null" or "[object Object]"

Comment: according to sample https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS/app.js#L35, we need  to use `args.entities`, and by the way, could you make sure that you have specific type if `place`?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT, yes I have cross-checked the entities. Tried with other intents for a different set of entities as well. Executing the code locally with console as the output produces the desired results. However, the code deployed to Bot Service doesn't seem to detect the entities. I have tried every possible combination from the list of samples posted on GItHub as well as the main documentation but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve entities, just use

```
<entity-name>.entity
```

where entity-name is your `var location`. I hope this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem before, have you tried the following code to see if your entities exist?

```
if(args.entities[0]) {
        session.send(args.entities[0]["entity"])
        session.send(args.entities[0]["type"])
}
```

If they do exist, how are your Environmental Variables and LuisModelUrl set up? If you are using the EVs and *"api.projectoxford.com"* as your LuisAPIHostName, try updating the host name to *"<your bot's location>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com".*